# Generating one NumPy array for each DataFrame row

Tags: pandas, mplfinance

I'm attempting to plot stock market trades against a plot of the particular stock using mplfinance.plot(). I keep record of all my trades using jstock which uses as CSV file:

```
"Code","Symbol","Date","Units","Purchase Price","Current Price","Purchase Value","Current Value","Gain/Loss Price","Gain/Loss Value","Gain/Loss %","Broker","Clearing Fee","Stamp Duty","Net Purchase Value","Net Gain/Loss Value","Net Gain/Loss %","Comment"
"ASO","Academy Sports and Outdoors, Inc.","Sep 13, 2021","25.0","45.85","46.62","1146.25","1165.5","0.769999999999996","19.25","1.6793893129770994","0.0","0.0","0.0","1146.25","19.25","1.6793893129770994",""
"ASO","Academy Sports and Outdoors, Inc.","Aug 26, 2021","15.0","41.3","46.62","619.5","699.3","5.32","79.79999999999995","12.881355932203384","0.0","0.0","0.0","619.5","79.79999999999995","12.881355932203384",""
"ASO","Academy Sports and Outdoors, Inc.","Jun 3, 2021","10.0","37.48","46.62","374.79999999999995","466.2","9.14","91.40000000000003","24.386339381003214","0.0","0.0","0.0","374.79999999999995","91.40000000000003","24.386339381003214",""
"RMBS","Rambus Inc.","Nov 24, 2021","2.0","26.99","26.99","53.98","53.98","0.0","0.0","0.0","0.0","0.0","0.0","53.98","0.0","0.0",""
```

I can get this data easily enough using

```
myportfolio = pd.read_csv(PORTFOLIO_LOCATION, parse_dates=[2])
```

But I need to create individual lists for each trade that match the day-by-day stock price:

```
Date,High,Low,Open,Close,Volume,Adj Close
2020-12-01,17.020000457763672,16.5,16.799999237060547,16.8799991607666,990900,16.8799991607666
2020-12-02,17.31999969482422,16.290000915527344,16.65999984741211,16.40999984741211,1200500,16.40999984741211
```

and I have a normal DataFrame containing this. So far this is what I have:

```
for i in myportfolio.groupby("Code"):
    (code, j) = i
    if code == "ASO": # just testing it against one stock
        simp = pd.DataFrame(columns=["Date", "Units", "Price"],
            data=j[["Date", "Units", "Purchase Price"]].values, index=j[["Date"]])
        df = pd.read_csv("ASO-2020-12-01-2021-12-01.csv", index_col=0, parse_dates=True)
        # df.lookup(simp["Date"])
        df.insert(0, 'row_num', range(0,len(df)))
        k = df.loc[simp["Date"]]['row_num']
        trades = []
        for index, m in k.iteritems():
            t = np.zeros((df.shape[0], 1))
            t.fill(np.nan)
            t[m] = simp[index]["Price"]
            trades.append(t.to_list())
```

But I receive a `KeyError: Timestamp('2021-09-17 00:00:00')`

Any ideas of how to fix this?

Addendum 1:

```
import pandas as pd
trade_data = [['ASO', '5/5/21', 10], ['ASO', '5/6/21', 12], ['RBLX', '5/7/21', 15]]
trade_df = pd.DataFrame(trade_data, columns = ['Code', 'Date', 'Price'])
trade_df['Date'] = pd.to_datetime(trade_df['Date'])
trade_df

    Code    Date    Price
0   ASO 2021-05-05  10
1   ASO 2021-05-07  12
2   RBLX    2021-05-07  15

aso_data = [['5/5/21', 12, 5, 10, 7], ['5/6/21', 15, 7, 13, 8], ['5/7/21', 17, 10, 15, 11]]
aso_df = pd.DataFrame(aso_data, columns = ['Date', 'High', 'Low', 'Open', 'Close'])
aso_df['Date'] = pd.to_datetime(aso_df['Date'])
aso_df

    Date    High    Low Open    Close
0   2021-05-05  12  5   10  7
1   2021-05-06  15  7   13  8
2   2021-05-07  17  10  15  11
```

So I want to create two NumPy arrays for ASO {one for each trade) and one for the RBLX trade. For ASO I should have two NumPy arrays that looks like `[10, Nan, Nan]` and `[NaN, NaN, 12]`.

Answer (score 0):

Do you want a list of lists right?
There is no need to loop.

```
df_list = df.values.tolist()
```

Comment: I'm trying to construct a list of np.array's, each np.appy containing only one value in one row whose contents line up one-to-one with df (the stock data). That is, each list contains one trade, whose row matches with the date in the df and contains the price of the trade. This is then plotted onto the stock chart.

Answer (score 0):

just in case another novice such as myself surfs in with a similar problem.

```
for i in myportfolio.groupby(["Code"]):
    (code, j) = i
    if code == "ASO": # just testing it against one stock
        df = pd.read_csv("ASO-2020-12-01-2021-12-01.csv", index_col=0, parse_dates=True)
        df.insert(0, 'row_num', range(0,len(df)))
        k = df.loc[j["Date"]]['row_num']
        trades = []
        for index, m in j.iterrows(): 
            t = np.zeros((df.shape[0], 1))
            t.fill(np.nan)
            t[int(df.loc[m["Date"]]['row_num'])] = m["Purchase Price"]
            asplot = mpf.make_addplot(t, type="scatter", color='red', marker="D")
            trades.append(asplot)
        mpf.plot(df, type='candle', addplot=trades)
```

produced an okay graph showing my entry points. good luck[image: stock price graph with red diamonds showing where and whwen i purchased shares]